# JQuery ajax call resets all form fields

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

I have been developing contact forms on my sites using captcha. An example can be seen here:

[contact form](http://www.avoidtherisk.com/contact_us.html)

Several years ago, if a user needed to reload the captcha image, the only choice I had then was to reload the entire form.

Since I started using jquery, it was time to replace this method with one that would just refresh the image.

So I wrote this little fragment:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#creload').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/en/KDpg_Captcha.html",
            async: true,
            success: function(ret) {
                $('#cimg').attr('src', ret);
            }
        });
    });
});​
```

where `#creload` is the id of the link requesting the reload and `#cimg` is the id of the actual image.

What I discovered is that if one fills in other form fields and then requests a reload, the other fields are reset. This is NOT a result to be desired.

What could I be missing?

Answer (score 2):

If #creload is a link you'll need to prevent it from doing it's default action which is opening what's in the href attribute. Adding [e.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) stops this. Don't forget to add **e** as an argument:

```
$('#creload').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // ...
```

Comment: Note to OP: don't forget to change `function()` to `function(e)` in order to assign the event object to `e`.

Answer (score 2):

When you click on the following link:

```
<a href id="creload">here</a>
```

the current page is interpreted as the `href` and the page is reloaded.

You can prevent this programmatically by adding `function(e)` and `e.preventDefault()` to your `click` handler as TJ describes, or more simply by changing the link to:

```
<a href="#" id="creload">here</a>
```

or, if you don't want the `#` link to take visitors to the top of the page:

```
<a href="javascript:" id="creload">here</a>
```

Comment: Note that `#` will also cause the link to take you to the top of the page.

Comment: @JamesMontagne Since in this case the link is also at the top of the page, this isn't significant. But I'll update my answer anyway, for the benefit of future readers.

Comment: well, i'm now very frustrated. first off, i realized that my ajax call was incorrect in that what i wanted to do was to change the actual image, not the src of the image. so i removed all the ajax and simply replaced it with

Comment: $('#cimg').load('/en/KDpg_Captcha.html') - which works until i add the call to preventDefault before it. and, it doesn't seem to matter whether or not the href is "", "#", or "javascript:". i really must be missing something....